# Get rid of inline CSS style attribute in confluence

Tags: css, confluence, confluence-macros

In Confluence Server deployment can give custom CSS file.

General Configuration -> Security Configuration -> Custom Stylesheet for spaces Can be enabled. When I view source the confluence page I can see CSS inline attributes. For example

{"serverDuration": 148, "requestCorrelationId": "cfc0fae0d17c7e90"}

How Can I completely get rid of css inline attributes replacing CSS classes ?

Answer (score 1):

That's not CSS attributes, it's some performance related information hidden on the page.

The velocity macro which generates it is:

```
#macro (confluenceServerPerformanceSpan)
    <span style="display:none;" id="confluence-server-performance">{"serverDuration": $generalUtil.getServerRenderTime($req).toMillis(), "requestCorrelationId": "$generalUtil.getRequestCorrelationId()"}</span>
#end
```